# How to make a keypad for JavaScript (number)

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a number analyzer on the JavaScript editor on https://khanacademy.org. I want to make it so my variable that is analyzed can be changed without changing the code. I am thinking the best way to do it is to make a keypad numbers 0-9. The only problem is that when I make a button for 1 and 2 and press both buttons the `theNumber` variable becomes 3 not 12. Can I fix this somehow?

code:

```
var theNumber = 0;
var numberOne = 0;
var numberTwo = 0;
if (mouseIsPressed&& a condition&& a condition&& a condition&& a condition) {
  numberOne = 1;
}
if (mouseIsPressed&& a condition&& a condition&& a condition&& a condition) {
  numberTwo = 2;
}  
theNumber = theNumber + numberOne + numberTwo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var theNumber = 0;` makes the variable 'theNumber' a number as opposed to a string. Therefore, when you do `theNumber = theNumber + numberOne + numberTwo` you get math addition as opposed to string concatenation. There are various ways around this. The snippet below shows how to change numeric values to strings by using quotes around the numbers:

```js
// Numbers
var theNumber1 = 1;
var theNumber2 = 2;
var theNumber3 = 3;
       
var theNumber = theNumber1 + theNumber2 + theNumber3

var elem = document.getElementById("x");
elem.innerHTML = theNumber;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

// Strings
var theNumber1 = "1";
var theNumber2 = "2";
var theNumber3 = "3";
       
var theNumber = theNumber1 + theNumber2 + theNumber3

var elem = document.getElementById("y");
elem.innerHTML = theNumber;
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are of the type [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). When you use the `+ operator`, the normal arithmetic "+" is calculated.

In your case you want to use the datatype [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). The `+ operator` will concatenate the string in this case.

```js
const numberOne = "1"
const numberTwo = "2"
console.log(numberOne + numberTwo)
```